# Javascript / jQuery select element event when selected option is re-selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a simple SELECT, with the jQuery chosen plug-in, that appears on the page many times.  At the top of the select is the option to "Add New".  The idea is that I show a dialog box if the user clicks on Add New.

Using the jQuery click event, it is easy and works fine the first time.  However, if the user cancels out of the dialog box and then clicks on Add New again, the click event does not fire.

I've tried adding a click event handler to the option itself with no success.  I've also tried it without the chosen plug in, and no luck.  I don't think chosen is the problem.

Here's a simple jsfiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/7cMEg/

```
$('.cls').chosen().change(function() { if ($(this).val()==='-1') alert('clicked'); });
```

Click on the select box, and pick Add New.  An alert will appear.  But now that Add New is selected, when you click on the select box and re-click Add New, nothing happens - the click event isn't fired.  Is there another event I can use?  Any other suggestions (maybe an unstyled hyper link)?

Comment: it is because there is no change happening when you are clicking the `Add New` second time

Answer (score 2):

Becuase the event is triggered on `change` and not on `click`. As value is not changed on second click so alert is not displayed.

Showing alert on click - [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7cMEg/5/)

Comment: OK, thanks. Your fiddle doesn't work in Safari v6.0.5 (my default browser).  It also does not work in Chrome v28.0.1500.71.  It works in Firefox v22.0.  I haven't bothered to try IE.  If I remove the " option" from the selector, it works in Safari but still not in Chrome, and becomes mildly annoying in Firefox (triggering on the click and release of the select box).

Comment: @BumptiousQBangwhistle: Its not a complete ready made solution. I havent tried it everywhere and dont have time to do so. Just wanted to pin point the problem. May be this will help you to reach out to the solution.